# asp.net mvc. I cant open a detail page, if i do i get a error: "internal server error 500"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm new on this website and I'm stuck with a server error. I tried everything and i just cant figure it out. I'm also new to asp.net mvc so I'm stil a noob.

I just got a feeling that there is something going on in my web.config.

So the error is that if you go to a certain detail page, you go to the error page that the previous programmer made and that error says: "internal server error"

I deleted that to see the original error message:

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

Runtime Error Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

The weird thing is that on my localhost it does work, its just the online website that has the error.

I'm just stuck at this point and need help :(

I don't know what most of the code means in the web.config but I don't want to leak something important so I'm kinda scared to post all the code, there are like publickeytokens and some other stuff

Comment: Are you able to debug your code and pointout which line in the code throws the error? Can you share little bit more detailed error message or the capture of error screen?

Comment: i cant really debug because locally it works. And with the error messages, thats really all im getting, its so global and not detailed. I tried to change things in the web.config like the errormode detailed or the customerror mode off, but that didnt change anything

Comment: You can always edit the important information in your project, but more information is needed if you are going to receive any help. Things like this: do you use Entity Framework or not? In the above commentary, you said that it works locally. So, if that's the case, the error must be in the way you deploy. Please give us more information! And, by the way... don't be scared, since you're at the beginning I don't think anybody will kill you because of this. ;)

Comment: Want me to just post all the code of my web.config? And where can i see if i use a entity framework?